# How to make an object that can inherit multiple times?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm learning the canvas API, and want to make a simple physics engine in doing so. After working with Backbone.js this summer, I've been inspired by their OO approach in JS.

Knowing my problem to solve, I'm going to propose my solution, but if you believe you have a better way of solving this problem, please say so.

```
// Obj is a general object that can be basically anything. (Ball, rock, ground plane)
var Obj = Extendable.extend(
    position : [0, 0], // Coordinates
    velocity : [0, 0], // Vector,
    acceleration : [0, 0], // Vector
    shape : (Shape)
);

var Ball = Obj.extend(
    shape : (Shape)
);

var ball1 = new Ball();
var ball2 = new Ball(initializer);
```

The goal is to be able to extend as many times as I want before calling `new Object();` If it's possible to have multiple inheritance as well, that would be great.

Right now I've come up with this:

```
var Extendable = {
    extend : function(methods) {
        var f = function() {
            if (this.init) this.init.apply(arguments);
        };

        f.prototype = Object.create(_.extend({}, this.prototype, methods));
        f.extend = this.extend;

        return f;
    }
};

//The problem is that this only allows the use of .extend() one time...
EDIT: Now half way working.
```

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I actually think I've found a solution. I'm going to test it a little and post an answer. The problem, if I actually have found a solution, was that I forgot the logics of _.extend(). It runs through the object without being able to maintain the prototype chain. It creates a completely new object that forgets everything about it's chain.

Comment: Added an answer if anyone else has the same problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way of solving this. The problem was that I was too blind to think about what _.extend() does behind the scenes. I used it only with what functionality it is said to give in mind. What I did NOT think about was the fact that even Prototype.js cannot magically merge a prototype chain with an object. (And they never did claim this either. They claim it can merge objects.)

So, only a small change is necessary to make it work:

```
extend : function(methods) {
    // Define a constructor that will be available on all "classes".
    var f = function() {
        if (this.init) this.init.apply(arguments);
    };

    // Add the current prototype to the chain. (Added in "methods"-argument in a previous extend.
    // Then we're going to add the new methods to the prototype.
    f.prototype = _.extend(Object.create(this.prototype || {}), methods);
    // Add the .extend() on the object to allow further inheritance.
    f.extend = this.extend;

    return f;
},
```